# FORMS multi-options to SP List by Power Automate

Tags: forms, sharepoint, power-automate

would like to save response from multi-options of FORMS to a multiple-choice type column in a SharePoint List using Power Automate to create new item in SP List, and I want to be able to differentiate each option in the field data rather than storing it as a single string from FORMS.

[In SP List, it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP9Po.png)

[But I would like it to be shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV0qV.png)

Not really sure which feature in Power Automate I can use to fix this issue?
Could anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test for your reference:
[image]
[image]

Here is flow:
(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rdaff92743db14f259d9a02752efd294f']) is QUestion(From forms choice)

```
@{json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rdaff92743db14f259d9a02752efd294f'])}
```

[image]
[image]

Here is test result:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is link for your reference:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/MS-Forms-Multiple-Choice-to-SharePoint-List-Create-a-new-Item/td-p/623975